# Singular value of block matrix and its submatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, singular-values

Consider two real matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, the target is to establish an inequality between
$$
\sigma_{\mathrm{max}}(\begin{bmatrix} A& B\end{bmatrix})
$$
and
$$
\sigma_{\mathrm{max}}(A), \text{ }\sigma_{\mathrm{max}}(B).
$$

My ***hypothesis*** is that
$$
\sigma_{\mathrm{max}}(\begin{bmatrix} A& B\end{bmatrix}) \geqslant \max\{\sigma_{\mathrm{max}}(A), \sigma_{\mathrm{max}}(B)\},
$$
which is trivial when both $A$ and $B$ are scalars. However, it is not clear for me how to prove it in general matrix cases.

---

It turns out that the proof is rather simple:
\begin{align}
&\sigma_{\mathrm{max}}(\begin{bmatrix} A& B\end{bmatrix}) = \sqrt{\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}(AA^\top +BB^\top)} \\ &\geqslant \max\{\sqrt{\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}(AA^\top )}, \sqrt{\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}(BB^\top )}\}= \max\{\sigma_{\mathrm{max}}(A), \sigma_{\mathrm{max}}(B)\}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

The proof you present is valid. Here's another.

$$
\begin{align}
\sigma_{\max} \pmatrix{A & B} &= \max_{x \in \Bbb R^{m+n}, \|x\|=1} \left\|\pmatrix{A & B}x \right\| 
\\ &= \max_{\|x_1\|^2 + \|x_2\|^2 = 1} \left\|\pmatrix{A & B}\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2} \right\|
\\ &\geq 
\max_{\|x_1\|^2 + \|x_2\|^2 = 1, \ x_2 = 0} \left\|\pmatrix{A & B}\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2} \right\|
 = \max_{\|x_1\| = 1} \|Ax\| = \sigma_{\max}(A).
\end{align}
$$
By a similar argument, $\sigma_{\max} \pmatrix{A & B} \geq \sigma_{\max}(B)$.